# Why do I get "Protocol http not supported or disabled in libcurl"?

Tags: opensuse, curl, zypper

I am trying to add a repository to my OpenSUSE Leap 42.3 (running on WSL) with the following command.

```
sudo zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo
```

I get the following error.

> Download (curl) error for
>   'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo':
>   Error code:  Bad URL Error message: Protocol http not supported or
>   disabled in libcurl

I find confusing the fact the error message is talking about http when I am using https as protocol, and still more confusing that the output of `curl --version` suggests https is a supported protocol.

> curl 7.37.0 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.37.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2j zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
>   Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
>   Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

With `zypper info libssl43`, I get the following output.

```
Information for package libssl43:
---------------------------------
Repository     : oss
Name           : libssl43
Version        : 2.5.3-6.1
Arch           : x86_64
Vendor         : openSUSE
Installed Size : 360.0 KiB
Installed      : Yes
Status         : up-to-date
Source package : libressl-2.5.3-6.1.src
Summary        : An SSL/TLS protocol implementation
Description    :
    LibreSSL is an open-source implementation of the Secure Sockets Layer
    (SSL) and Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocols. It derives from
    OpenSSL and intends to provide a more secure implementation.
```

The output of `zypper info libcrypto41` is the following. (libcrypto41 is a dependency of libssl43.)

```
Information for package libcrypto41:
------------------------------------
Repository     : oss
Name           : libcrypto41
Version        : 2.5.3-6.1
Arch           : x86_64
Vendor         : openSUSE
Installed Size : 2.0 MiB
Installed      : Yes (automatically)
Status         : up-to-date
Source package : libressl-2.5.3-6.1.src
Summary        : An SSL/TLS protocol implementation
Description    :
    The "crypto" library implements a wide range of cryptographic
    algorithms used in various Internet standards. The services provided
    by this library are used by the LibreSSL implementations of SSL, TLS
    and S/MIME, and they have also been used to implement SSH, OpenPGP,
    and other cryptographic standards.
```

How can I use https URLs? I could instead use http, but I would prefer not going through that path.

Comment: looks like libssl issue

Comment: For everyone facing this: Before debugging your `ssl` libraries, make sure to check your URLs, especially when being created dynamically. Slight typos like `https ://` (note the space) just (mis-)lead me to this error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [Thread: zypper https urls: Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/527186-zypper-https-urls-Protocol-quot-http-quot-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl), which contains a link to [Thread: Cached files in /home/~/.cache/kioexec/krun/####_# ? How to avoid?](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/527052-Cached-files-in-home-cache-kioexec-krun-_-How-to-avoid?p=2838330#post2838330)

Following what said in those posts, I tried `curl https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo`, which outputs the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:/php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.34 (Linux/SUSE) Server at download.opensuse.org Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

So, `https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo` is redirected to `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:/php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo` and, since the redirect is from https:// to http://, it is not followed by Zypper.

In short, the server is not yet working using https:// URLs, and the temporary work-around is to use http:// URLs. Nothing is wrong in my OpenSuse 42.3 installation.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can manually add (as root) the following file under `/etc/zypp/repos.d/php.repo` with contents

```
[devel_languages_php]
name=devel:languages:php (openSUSE_Leap_42.3)
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
```

which is the contents of the above URL: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo