# Unable to run `zypper refresh` on SLES 12.5

Tags: docker, curl, sles, zypper

I am trying to install docker on SLES 12.5. I tried to follow the instructions on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55367954/4135063).

## Initial Attempt

```
# zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:containers/SLE_12_SP5/Virtualization:containers.repo
Adding repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' ...........................................................................................................[done]
Repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' successfully added

URI         : https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/
Enabled     : Yes
GPG Check   : Yes
Autorefresh : No
Priority    : 99 (default priority)

Repository priorities are without effect. All enabled repositories share the same priority.
```

```
# zypper refresh
Repository 'SLES12-SP5-Pool' is up to date.
Repository 'SLES12-SP5-Updates' is up to date.
Repository 'Update' is up to date.
Retrieving repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' metadata -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[-]
Download (curl) error for 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/repodata/a02bda6c6525d5d550e34e98844bf0e18a66aa1a24282c72a80c4679ef2e121d-primary.xml.gz':
Error code:  Bad URL
Error message: Redirect to protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/...? shows all options] (a): a
Retrieving repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' metadata .............................................................................................[error]
Repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' is invalid.
[Virtualization_containers|https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Skipping repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' because of the above error.
Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.
```

## Second Attempt

I found [this question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399715/163490) with a similar error, so I edited the `/etc/zypp/repos.d/Virtualization_containers.repo` file as follows:

### Before:

```
[Virtualization_containers]
name=Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)
enabled=1
autorefresh=0
baseurl=https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/
type=rpm-md
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/repodata/repomd.xml.key
```

### After:

```
[Virtualization_containers]
name=Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)
enabled=1
autorefresh=0
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/
type=rpm-md
```

Then tried again:

```
# zypper refresh
Repository 'SLES12-SP5-Pool' is up to date.
Repository 'SLES12-SP5-Updates' is up to date.
Repository 'Update' is up to date.
Retrieving repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' metadata -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[/]
Timeout exceeded when accessing 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/repodata/a02bda6c6525d5d550e34e98844bf0e18a66aa1a24282c72a80c4679ef2e121d-primary.xml.gz'.
Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i] (r): i
Autoselecting 'r' after 7 seconds.
Retrieving repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' metadata .............................................................................................[error]
Repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' is invalid.
[Virtualization_containers|http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Skipping repository 'Virtualization:containers (SLE_12_SP5)' because of the above error.
Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.
```

## Third Attempt

I tried to give up on zypper and use another installation method. I found an RPM file [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=Virtualization%3Acontainers&package=docker#directSLE)

https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/x86_64/docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64.rpm

```
myserver:~/temp # systemctl stop docker
myserver:~/temp # docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
myserver:~/temp # rpm -ivh docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        catatonit is needed by docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64
        containerd-git = 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429 is needed by docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64
        docker-libnetwork-git = 026aabaa659832804b01754aaadd2c0f420c68b6 is needed by docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64
        docker-runc-git = dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd is needed by docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64
        fix_bsc_1057743 is needed by docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/x86_64/docker-19.03.12_ce-378.39.x86_64.rpm
```

## Question

So how can I install Docker on SLES 12.5? Can I fix `Redirect to protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl`?

Comment: Have you considered [searching the web](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=zypper+Redirect+to+protocol+%22http%22+not+supported+or+disabled+in+libcurl)?

Comment: @berndbausch Yes.

Comment: My point is, there are plenty of suggestions. It is hard to imagine that people who don't know your server's configuration can come up with better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here.

Attempt 2 should have worked, but that specific URL (`http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/repodata/a02bda6c6525d5d550e34e98844bf0e18a66aa1a24282c72a80c4679ef2e121d-primary.xml.gz`) was being automatically redirected to one of the various opensuse repository mirrors. I figured it out by trying to download it directly via `wget` and it showed the redirect. This particular mirror was unreachable (hence the timeout) due to a network connectivity allowlist that did not include it. The fix was to include this mirror in the allowlist.