# How to install git on SLES 12?

Tags: curl, git, sles, zypper

This is similar to the [question about http not supported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399715/why-do-i-get-protocol-http-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl), but I was not able to apply the solutions suggested there to my situation.

I've done

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:tools:scm/SLE_12_SP5/devel:tools:scm.repo
zypper refresh
```

and I'm getting

```
Retrieving repository 'Software configuration management (SLE_12_SP5)' met
Download (curl) error for 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devels:/scm/SLE_12_SP5/repodata/8ff6d5e77f953a771c9870113c655dfef8cf31ffba709feec8e0a617fc-primary.xml.gz':
Error code:  Bad URL
Error message: Redirect to protocol "http" not supported or disabled in li
```

Now if I

```
curl https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/tools:/scm/SLE_12_SP5/repodata/8ff6d5e77f953a771c9870113c655dfef8cf31ffba709f2506cceec8e0a617fc-primary.xml.gz
```

I see

```
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://downloadcontent.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/tools:/scm/SLE_12_SP5/repodata/8ff6d5e77f953a771c9870113c655dfef8cf31ffba709f2506cceec8e0a617fc-primary.xml.gz">here</a>.</p>
```

But if I try to apply the solution suggested in the related question with a

```
vi /etc/zypp/repos.d/devel_tools_scm.repo
```

and I change https in http, then it does not work because the http URL does (no longer?) exist: `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:php.repo`

What am I doing wrong or what am I supposed to do to install git so?

Comment: Before you did all of that, did `zypper install git` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've indicated that what I mentioned in my comment worked after you tried it, I'm going to post it as an answer:

```
zypper install git
```

`git` is available in the SLES repos as it is in the repos for nearly every other distribution. In the case of SLES, the above command will install it as long as the repos are enabled.

Comment: Btw what if I need to install a version of something that is not available from zypper? I see that there is `zypper install python36` but I would prefer python 3.9 on my SLES 12.5 : is it not doable? Thank you again

Comment: There are repos that you can add that have it but the best way is to build it from source and add it to your environment to avoid conflicts.